# Polynomial $P(a)=b,P(b)=c,P(c)=a$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $a,b,c$ be $3$ distinct integers, and let $P$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients.Show that in this case the conditions $$P(a)=b,P(b)=c,P(c)=a$$ cannot be satisfied simultaneously.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the integer coefficients positive or need not be?

Comment: It would be too easy

Comment: Since there was no such condition given in the question I guess they need not be positive.

Comment: @Harold:Exactly.Since in that case,P(a)>a

Comment: Pairwise different means each pair is different $\,a\ne b,\ b\ne c,\ c\ne a\ \ $

Comment: What's the difference between pairwise different and different?

Comment: @Il It's a more precise way of stating it. "Different" could instead possibly mean "not all are equal", [compare](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/64019/242) "coprime" vs. "pairwise coprime".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806322/proving-no-polynomial-px-exists-such-that-pa-b-pb-c-pc-a

Comment: No it is impossible use the fact if $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients then $a-b \mid P(a)-P(b)$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint:** If $P(a)=b$ and $P(b)=c$ then $a-b$ divides $b-c$.

Comment: Then we can do it using contradiction.Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. There are still a few lines to write, and one has to be careful.

Answer (score 10):

**Lemma**:If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients then $a-b \mid P(a)-P(b)$

**Proof**:Take $P(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{1}x+a_0$

Then You cold easily prove the lemma by the identity $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}a^\ell b^{k-\ell-1}$$

So we have:

$$b-c \mid a-b$$$$a-b \mid c-a$$
$$c-a \mid b-c$$

Which gives us $b-c \mid a-b \mid c-a \mid b-c$.

$$\Rightarrow \mid b-c \mid \ge \mid a-b \mid \ge \mid c-a \mid \ge \mid b-c \mid$$

then :

$\mid b-c \mid =\mid a-b \mid =\mid c-a \mid$

The problem is cyclic so without loss of generality we can take $a=max\{a,b,c\}$.So we have:

$a-b=a-c \Rightarrow b=c$

Which is wrong.

Comment: You may want to add that the lemma follows from the identity: $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}a^\ell b^{k-\ell-1}.$$

Comment: @C.Falcon Thank You added.

Comment: You can't just assume that $a>b>c$ in the end; other cases should be checked as well

Comment: @barto because it has the same calculation I didn't bring them.

Comment: @TahaAkbari No. You seem to assume that $a>b>c$ up to _cyclic_ permutation (which indeed gives the same system), whereas e.g. the case $b>a>c$ gives the substantially different $b-c=b-a=a-c$. (I'm not denying they're trivial to check, merely remarking upon the error of saying "Wlog, let $a>b>c$.")

Comment: @barto Yes it seems you are right but again in every case we will get to the same resault $a=b=c$

Comment: @barto I think now the proof is ok.Yes?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ a\!-\!b\mid P(a)\!-\!P(b) = b\!-\!c.\,$ By symmetry $\,b\!-\!c\mid c\!-\!a,\ \ c\!-\!a\mid a\!-\!b.\ $ Chained, these yield a divisibility *cycle* $\ \color{#c00}j\mid k\mid n\mid \color{#c00} j,\  $ so $\ k,n = \pm j.\ $ But $\,j+k+n = 0\,\Rightarrow\, j=0\,\Rightarrow\,a=b\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

**Remark** $ $ The divisibility is a specialization of the **Factor Theorem** $\,x-b\mid P(x)-P(b)\,$ or the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\bmod a\!-\!b\!:\  a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, P(a)\equiv P(b),\ $ for $\,P\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1199704/242)

**Note** $\ $
This (accepted) answer was merged from [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123628/242) so comments, votes, etc might not be in sync.

Comment: I don't know how to bite that

Comment: @II What divisibility statements do you have available to chain into a cycle?

Comment: I don't know what is chaining into a cycle

Comment: @II A divisibility cycle looks like this  $\ \color{#c00}j\mid k\mid n\mid \color{#c00} j\,\ $ (view them as a circle / cycle, since they cycle back to the original number).

Comment: can you show me exactly how does it look like?

Comment: @Il When you permute $\,a,b,c\,$ you will have three divisibility relations that you can put in a cycle like that. What can you then deduce about $\,k,n\,$ given how they are "squeezed" between $j$'s? $\ \ $

Comment: $\frac{\frac{P(a)}{a}}{\frac{b}{P(a)}}=\frac{\frac{P(c)}{a}}{x}$ solve for x and get $x=\frac{b}{P(a)}$ and we get $P(a)xca=P(b)P(c)b$ is my way of thinking correct?

Comment: so $\frac{P(c)}{\frac{b}{P(a)}}=1$ $ab$ is not $b$ which is false did i solve it?

Comment: @Il Huh? You are supposed to begin with the divisibility $\, a-b\mid b-c.\,$ That's our $\,j\mid k\,$ above. You will get two more such divisibilities $\,k\mid n\,$ and $\, n\mid j\,$  from symmetry, by permuting $\,a,b,c.\,$ Chain them into a cycle as above, then deduce something from the "squeezing".

Comment: @Il I added more detail to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As known, $p(a)=b$  $\implies p(b)=p(p(a))=c\implies p(c)=p(p(p(a)))=a$.
Which implies that the polynomial is of the kind $p(x)=x$. So,we get $p(a)=a$ and we also know that $p(a)=c$. So $c=a$. A contradiction  ($a,b,c$ are distinct)

Comment: Why should $p(p(p(a))) = a$ mean that $p(a) = a$? Note that $p(x) = \frac{1}{2}(-3x^2 + 11x - 4)$ has $p(p(p(1))) = 1$, it just doesn't have integer coefficients.

Comment: @BenMillwood if $p(p(p(x)))=x$ for all $x$, then by observing the degree of the polynomial and trivially remaining cases, one has $p(x)=x$.  Not sure what to do if it doesn't hold for all $x$ though.

Comment: @SimpleArt In this case it is only known that $p(p(p(x)))=x$ is true for three distinct $x$, namely $a,b,c$, not for all $x$, though you seem to understand it.

Comment: This answer needs editing. It is not clear how one concludes that $p$ is identity. To be honest, this is the same idea I had when I first read the question, but I don't see that it works, actually. From what is written, one can conclude that $(\deg p)^3 \geq 3$ but it needs clarification why this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Very late reply, but as a proof I posted to this problem was marked as a duplicate to this one, I thought I would repost it as an answer here in the off-chance someone might find the reasoning useful. This proof does not assume the divisibility cycle theorem mentioned in other answers (actually, it shows how the specific case $n=3$ of the theorem can be derived).

**Proof:** Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients. Assume there exist three distinct integers $a,b, c$ such that 
$$P(a)=b, P(b)=c, P(c)=a.$$
Since the integers are distinct, there is a least among them. Without loss of generality, write $a<b$ and $a<c$.

Note that, for any two real numbers $x,y$,
$$P(x)-P(y)=a_n(x^n - y^n)+a_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1})+ \cdots +a_1(x-y).$$

So, using the identity
$$x^n -y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+ \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}),$$

it follows that
$$P(x)- P(y)=(x-y)Q(x,y),$$
where $Q(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $x,y$, of degree $(n-1)$. Examining the properties of $Q$ will give us the contradiction we seek.  Plugging the values $a,b$ into the above gives
$$P(a)-P(b)=(a-b)Q(a,b)=b-c.$$

By our construction of $Q$, it is clear that, just as $P$, it too must have integer coefficients; and so we can write $Q(a,b)=m_1$, for some integer $m_1$. This same argument eventually gives the following three equations:
$$\begin{align} \tag{1} (a-b)m_1=b-c  \\ \tag{2}(b-c)m_2=c-a  \\ \tag{3} (c-a)m_3=a-b \end{align} .$$

Since the integers $a,b,c$ are distinct, $m_i\neq 0$ for any $i$.

Next, divide (1) by (2):

$$\tag{1’} \frac{a-b}{c-a} m_1=\frac{1}{m_2}.$$

Dividing both sides of $(3)$ by $m_3$ and then taking the reciprocal gives:

$$\tag{3’} \frac{1}{c-a}=\frac{m_3}{a-b}.$$

Substituting $(3’)$ into $(1’)$ finally yields the following equation:

$$m_1 m_3=\frac{1}{m_2},$$

which means  $m_i=\pm 1$ for all $i$. This implies $m_3=-1 \implies a-c=a-b \implies c=b$, which is a contradiction. $\quad \square$

**Corollary 1**: Let $j,k,l$ be integers such that ${\color{DarkRed}j }| k , k | l , l | {\color{DarkRed}j } $, then $k, l= \pm j$.

**Proof**: By definition $j m_1=k$, $km_2=l$,$lm_3=j$, and since we have shown in this case the $m_i= \pm 1$ for all $i$, the result follows. $\quad \square$

**Corollary 2**: Let $S=(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ be any set of $n$ integers, $n\geq 2$, such that $$a_1 \mid a_2\mid \cdots \mid a_n \mid a_1,$$
then $a_i = \pm a_1$.

**Proof**: This is a straight-forward proof by induction. The case $n=2$ is just a simpler version of the proof for $n=3$ given above.

Next, is the inductive hypothesis. Assume that, for any set of $n-1$ integers which satisfy a division cycle, then $a_i=\pm a_1$ for all $i$, $1\leq i \leq n-1$. Next, assume there is a set S as above.

Since $a_{n-1}m_1=a_{n}$ and $a_n m_2=a_1$, it follows that $a_{n-1} \mid a_1$. Without loss of generality we  can write $a_1\mid a_n \mid a_1 \implies a_n= \pm a_1$, which completes the proof. $\quad \square$