# Proving no polynomial $P(x)$ exists such that $P(a) = b$, $P(b) = c$, $P(c) = a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $a, b ,c$ are three distinct integers, then show that it is impossible to have $P(a) = b$, $P(b) = c$, $P(c) = a$.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what happens under Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387721/polynomial-pa-b-pb-c-pc-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $b-c$ is divisible by $a-b$, and ...

Comment: I got your point but what next

Comment: ... and $a-b$ is divisible by $c-a$, and ...

Comment: This is an old USAMO, I think.