# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $f(a)=b, f(b)=c, f(c)=a$ Then Prove that $a=b=c$.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ With integer coefficient. If for natural numbers $a,b,c$, 
$f(a)=b, f(b)=c, f(c)=a$
Prove that $a=b=c$.

Comment: Should it be $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$?

Comment: It seems likely that we are expected to assume $f$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: Yes it is integral coefficients.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123628/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For the modified question, note that $a-b$ divides $f(a)-f(b)$.

So $a-b$ divides $b-c$. Similarly, $b-c$ divides $c-a$ and $c-a$ divides $a-b$.

Answer (score 9):

This is not true: Consider the polynomial $f(x)=-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{11x}{2}-2$. Then $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=1$.

(Edit: This is the answer to a previous version of the question, which didn't specify that the coefficients must be integers. For a hint or an answer to the modified version, see André Nicolas' answer above or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123628/polynomials-prove-exercise-question-about-question).)

Comment: The question has been modified, but your answer to the previous version is still valuable. It may be a good idea to modify the answer to make clear what it answers.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion!