# Question about polynomials and elements of random rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I've recently read in a book a proof that used the following fact:

> Since $(X^m-1, X^n+1)=1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X],$ there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $$(X^m-1)u + (X^n+1)v = 2$$
>   hence $(b^m-1)u(b) + (b^n+1)v(b) = 2 \quad (*)$

For context, $b$ is a random element of a finite ring $A$ with unity.

My question is the following: how were they able to get to $(*)?$ Are the rings $A[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ somehow connected? How is $u(b)$ even defined, as $u \in \mathbb{Z}[X]?$

Comment: By evaluating at $b$ (more technically by using the universal property of $\Bbb Z[X])$.  Polynomial equations in $\Bbb Z[X]$ (such as Bezout equations) can be considered as universal laws (identities) of commutative rings, e.g. see [GCD in a PID persists in extension domains.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242)

Comment: Thank you! But in this example the ring is not necessary commutative. Is this because only one element of the ring is involved in the polynomial equation? (i.e. $b$)

Comment: Hint: the proof of the Bezout equation in $\Bbb Z[X]$ uses only ring laws plus the hypothesis that $X$ commutes with all elements in the coefficient ring $\Bbb Z$, so the Bezout equation will persist in the image ring if the latter commutativity constraint persists.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213572/242) on the role that commutativity plays in the proof that polynomial evaluation is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882417/242) for further examples of such universal equations and related ideas (the matrix examples there should shed light on the question in your first comment)