# Proof that a-b divides f(a) - f(b).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, polynomials

Given a polynomial function f(x), prove that f(a) - f(b) is divisible by a - b. I tried it with a few examples and it is coming out to be true. Is it true and if so how do we prove it ? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $a - b \mid f(a) - f(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198224/show-that-a-b-mid-fa-fb)

Comment: @WuDaozi Do you know how to calculate polynomial division? Try $\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}$, $\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}$, $\frac{a^4-b^4}{a-b}$, and see what pattern emerges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show first that it is true for monomials. Then for the general case, order terms by degree.