# Show $2^{55} + 1$ divisible by 33 using only basic identities

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

I'm working my way through *The Mathematical Olympiad Handbook* by A. Gardiner.

In the section *A little useful mathematics* right at the start the following basic identities are laid out

- $x^n -1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + ... + 1)$
- $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + ... + y^{n-1})$
- $x^n + 1 = (x+1)(x^{n-1} + ... + 1)$
- $x^n + y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + ... + y^{n-1})$

In this context the following two exercises are posed

1. Prove $2^{55} + 1$ is divisible by $33$
2. Prove $1900^{1990} -1$ is divisible by $1991$

So for (1) the strong implication seems to be to somehow use the fact that $33=2^5+1=(2+1)(2^4-2^3+2^2-2^1+1)$ and use that, but other than realising that I am slightly lost.

I can see using Fermat's Little Theorem allows an attack ($2^{55}=(2^5)^{11}$ etc.) but how to do it with just those identities I can't see it as Fermat's Little Theorem is used later as a second proof of this problem in the number theory section.

Can anyone see how to do it?

Comment: Hint for $1.$ : Show that divisibility by $3$ and by $11$

Comment: @Peter I believe OP wants it done via the "basic identities that are laid out" rather than "Fermat's Little Theorem that comes later".

Comment: @CalvinLin  The approach also works without FLT. I admit that here we can do better.

Comment: @Peter Interesting. I get the $ 2+1 = 3$. Can you write up how to show it is divisible by 11 (without showing 33 directly)?

Comment: @CalvinLin We can use $2^5\equiv -1\mod 11$

Comment: @Peter My point is that you're factoring out $2^5 + 1 = 33$ (IE using the basic identities), so the hint of "show divisibility by 3 and by 11" suggests doing them completely independently of each other, vs the approach suggested by the solutions below. $\quad$ Apart from that, we're saying the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117449/discussion-between-peter-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: Hint: in $\,X-Y\mid X^n - Y^n$ specialize $\,X,Y = x^k,y^k\,$ to the needed powers. Same for $\,X^n + Y^n.\,$ More generally we can use the [Polynomial Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1199704/242). It is easier using equations (congruences) vs. relations (divisibility), see the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$2^{55} +1 =(2^5)^{11} +1 = 32^{11} +1 = (32+1)(\dots) $$ using your third identity.

Comment: Thanks seems so obvious now. I am struggling to use a similar technique to crack $1900^{1990}-1$ divisible by 1991. Any idea?

Comment: @Gau55man Have you copied down the problem correctly? Wolfram says that is not true https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+Is+%281900%5E%281990%29-1%29%2F1991+an+integer

Comment: Yes I've triple checked $1900^{1990} -1$ is divisible by 1991. Most sensible pattern would mean what was intended was $1990^{1990}-1$ is divisible by $1991$ I'm guessing.

Comment: @Gau55man What have you checked it with?

Comment: I meant I tripled checked that is what the questions says so there is a typo/mistake in my book. I'm assuming intention is $1990^{1990} -1$ which admits solution by recognising as others have that $(1990^2)^{955} -1 = (1990^2 - 1)(...)$ then using identity $n^2 -1=(n+1)(n-1)$ which gives $1990^2 -1=1991 \cdot 1989$ showing that 1991 is a factor.

Comment: @Gau55man Yes, that is probably the case.

Answer (score 3):

$$(2^{5})^{11} + 1 = 32^{11} + 1 \overset * \equiv (-1)^{11} + 1 = 0 \pmod{33}$$
$(*)$: $32 = 33 - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod {33}$

Answer (score 1):

For divisibility of $2^{55}+1$ by $33,$ we can write
$$2^{55}+1=(2^{5})^{11}+1=(33-1)^{11}+1,$$ and apply the third identity.

Isn't there a typo in the second exercise? I suggest to prove divisibility of $1990^{1990} -1$ by $1991$ instead.  We have
$$1990^2 -1=1991\times 1989$$ and use the first identity.

Comment: $1900^2-1 \ne 1991\times 1989 $

Comment: You're right. I was rewriting it while you were posting your comment. Then I noticed you also think there is a typo in OP.